# Drupal Commerce Rules if Paypal Payment Method is Selected

Tags: commerce

What's the best event trigger for the following:

- Remove all Taxes if Payment method selected is Paypal.
- Add %3 to Total if Payment method selected is Paypal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event

```
'After updating an existing commerce order'
```

on condition

`'Selected payment method comparison'` under commerce Payment and select its value to `'Paypal'`

Now in action add `'Remove taxes applied to a line item'` and another action 'Add an item to list' to add %3 amount to total .

It will perform accordingly.

Hope it will work for you!